# Will questions be marked as duplicated again after re-open?

Tags: discussion, questions, reopen-closed

I just want to know how the system in Stack Overflow works. If a question has been marked as duplicated and it reopened after edited by the user, will it be closed again if the edited question is duplicated on another post?

Comment: If it's STILL a duplicate or a duplicate of another question, then yes.

Comment: It should be.  Whether that actually happens...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After reopening, all close options appear again (but not for the first round of close-voters, you can only *successfully* vote to close once and vote to reopen once - for expired votes, you can cast another vote after a period of time of at least a couple weeks, but not right away).

So if after reopening it still proves to be a duplicate, it can just be closed as a duplicate again, but by different users. Those users can even choose the same duplicate target.

Comment: Who are controlling? For those who has a higher reputation?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're asking. Are you saying you don't trust people who vote to close as duplicate, and you wonder who checks their actions? The community does. Or is suposed to.

Comment: Who has the right on marking the question as duplicated? I'm  just curious :/

Comment: Almost everyone can.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks for the info ^^

Comment: @Blast you can flag posts from 15 rep.

Comment: So after the question re-open, the first round of close-voters cannot vote the post ?

Comment: @JohnJoe that's correct.

Comment: @CodeCaster you need 50 to flag as duplicated, since they introduce a comment.

Comment: @Zoe I believe it's 21 days, maybe a little more.